# Command "git [command] --help" opens as HTML in my code editor - no output to terminal. How do I revert to default behavior?

Tags: git, bash, versioning

When I type `git reset --help` I don't get output in the bash terminal, but a new tab opens in my code editor to reveal some dense HTML.  How can I change Git's behavior to display the help message in the bash terminal?  I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Update:**

.gitconfig file:

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe' -w
[user]
    name = name
    email = 'email
    name = 'name
```

```
$ type -a git
git is /mingw64/bin/git
git is /mingw64/bin/git
git is /cmd/git
```

**Update 2:**

It looks like `help.format` is set to html, but after my user.name and other info, `help.format` is set to web (I did this).  I tried setting the browser using multiple browser names, but git fails to launch the help command in the browser and still opens in my code editor.

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
user.name=name
help.format=web

$ git reset --help
git config option web.browser set to unknown browser: edge
Resetting to default...
```

Comment: Hi Craig, Welcome to DevOps.SE.  Thanks for the helpful updates to your question.  I've tried extending my answer in a useful direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the default behavior of `git` so you have made some local config change to cause this to happen.  Look in your `~/.gitconfig` to see if there's anything that doesn't make sense to you.  Try commenting it out.  The `core.pager` setting is one of the first things I would check.  [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183900/2002471) has a variety of options for dealing with this sort of thing.

### update 1

I haven't tried to get this sort of thing to work, but according to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help#_configuration_variables) you can also specify a `man.viewer` to define the program that is going to run.  Do you get any errors if you try `git help -w reset`?

One work around would be to get the help to show up in the terminal by using `git help -m reset`.  By using the `help` subcommand instead of `subcommand --help` you can specify whether you want it to try man, info, or web.

Comment: Also check what `git` is: `type -a git`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out to reset your git config setting

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853986/easiest-way-to-reset-git-config-file

second thing, if you want output of help then you can use the "git reset -h" command which shows you minimal option of usage in your bash terminal whereas "git reset --help" command will be direct you to html format which is more descriptive explanation of command.

I hope this will help you.